# GCP http2 is working while disabled on cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, relational-database

I'm working on a service that needs immense resources every ~6 hours for about 15-20 minutes. This service needs access to my database.

The problem I'm facing is that I am using Google Cloud SQL to host my psql instance, for which I need to give a lot of computing power, and therefore cost, to handle the immense resources needed every ~6 hours; however, I don't want to pay for the resources when I don't use them.

Is there an architecture that auto-scales the resources when they are needed to a relational SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, or at least in GCP there isn't: [Google Cloud Platform Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/serverless/whitepaper#storing_your_application_data)

However; cockroach offers a solution:
[cockroachlabs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/lp/serverless/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=g_search_serv-launch-beta-brand_emea_bofu_phrase&utm_term=p-cockroach%20db%20serverless-c&utm_content=lp554144525689&utm_network=g&_bt=554144525689&_bk=cockroach%20db%20serverless&_bm=p&_bn=g&gclid=CjwKCAiAlfqOBhAeEiwAYi43FxUhm4gf7dsaLUbyoYPj2NPdhPcfF7PqKql1bc2tPt3v3DZpi3_G_BoCJ-IQAvD_BwE)